# Run bash script with "live" output in a Python Script?

Tags: python, shell

I'd like to know if it's possible to run a bash script inside a Python Script and get the bash script output "live" (not after the Python script ran the bash script, I know how to do that).

You'd probably ask me why I want to use a Python Script : actually I'd like build a nice CLI interface and I'm using Inquirer to do that. This interface allows the user to perform task that are actually performed using bash scripts. That's why I'm not using a bash script that executes other scripts.

Comment: Share some code about what you have done till now

Comment: You will have to use the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) class and capture the output files (`stderr` and `stdout`).

Comment: So you want to capture the input data from the terminal "live"?

Comment: I wanted to capture the script output and print it live, I didn't want to wait until the end of bash script execution. milanbalazs' answer is accurate and solves my problem !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following implementation to get the STDOUT of shell script in real-time.

**Code:**

```
cmd="whoami"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(line)
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
b'milanbalazs\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wanted to do !